# prosilica intrinsincs parameters failed to load

Tags: ros, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All,

I'm experiencing problems with a GC1380C prosilica camera. The camera is connected through a fast Ethernet interface, which I know is not optimal but still the SampleViewer works. I've access to different parameters, I can modify them, I can see the video stream etc...
However, whenever I'm trying to use the camera as follow : roslaunch prosilica.launch, I'm getting error :

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /prosilica_driver/trigger_mode
 * /rosdistro
 * /prosilica_driver/ip_address

NODES
  /
    prosilica_driver (prosilica_camera/prosilica_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [9439]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 1ee20ff0-9668-11e0-92a6-705ab6776520
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9452]
started core service [/rosout]
process[prosilica_driver-2]: started with pid [9455]
[ WARN] [1308043480.937092818]: Detected max data rate is 12400000 bytes/s, typical         maximum data rate for a GigE port is 115000000 bytes/s. Are you using a GigE network card and cable?

[ INFO] [1308043480.950345618]: Found camera, guid = 37112
[ WARN] [1308043480.951187554]: Failed to load intrinsics from camera
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'prosilica::ProsilicaException'
  what():  Couldn't get range of attribute StreamBytesPerSecond: Camera was unplugged
[prosilica_driver-2] process has died [pid 9455, exit code -6].
log files: /home/iis-xs/.ros/log/1ee20ff0-9668-11e0-92a6-705ab6776520/prosilica_driver-    2*.log
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

The IP address in prosilica.launch is the good one. Any idea what could be the origin of this error ?

Thank you very much,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10248/prosilica-intrinsincs-parameters-failed-to-load/) by [YBLD](https://answers.ros.org/users/689/ybld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank very much for your help. It tried both methods. I actually have dropped packets.
The log is :

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,089: init_node, name[/runtime_monitor_11983_1308236410083], pid[11983]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,090: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,090: Started XML-RPC server [http://iis-xs-Satellite-Pro-L500:34239/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,090: ROS Slave URI: [http://iis-xs-Satellite-Pro-L500:34239/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,090: _ready: http://iis-xs-Satellite-Pro-L500:34239/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,093: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,094: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,191: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,192: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,196: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2011-06-16 17:00:10,199: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.internal][WARNING] 2011-06-16 17:00:28,642: Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to iis-xs-Satellite-Pro-L500:38642 (http://iis-xs-Satellite-Pro-L500:56842/): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 472, in connect
    self.socket.connect((dest_addr, dest_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

From the Sample Viewer, I tune the packet size to 1500 which seems to work. However, it seems that the driver tries to optimize this size and as a result change it a larger value, which cause the Sample Viewer to crash too. When I use the SDK taken from Prosilica website, I do not encounter such issues using the same fast Ethernet interface. I can't actually change to network interface as I'm using a laptop. I'm currently checking if there is a problem in the driver code.

---

Originally posted by [YBLD](https://answers.ros.org/users/689/ybld/) with karma: 16 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2014-02-22**:
Hi
Did you find the problem in the end? I am also having problems with the prosilica_camera. I also get "failed to load intrinsics from camera"